# Calculate compounded return with external cashflows

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative price of a time series in the face of external cashflows.

This is the sample dataset:

```
reportdate  fund     mtd_return cashflow    Desired Output
30/11/2018  Fund X  -0.00860    15687713    15552798.98
31/12/2018  Fund X  -0.00900                15412823.78
31/01/2019  Fund X   0.00920                15554621.76
28/02/2019  Fund X   0.00630                15652615.88
31/03/2019  Fund X   0.00700                15762184.19
30/04/2019  Fund X   0.01220                15954482.84
31/05/2019  Fund X   0.00060    1000000     16964655.53
30/06/2019  Fund X   0.00570    1200000     18268194.07
31/07/2019  Fund X   0.00450                18350400.94
31/08/2019  Fund X   0.00210                18388936.78
30/09/2019  Fund X   0.00530                18486398.15
31/10/2019  Fund X   0.00200                18523370.94
30/11/2019  Fund X   0.00430                18603021.44
31/12/2019  Fund X   0.00660                18725801.38
31/01/2020  Fund X   0.01070                18926167.45
29/02/2020  Fund X  -0.00510                18829644.00
31/03/2020  Fund X  -0.10700                16814872.09
30/04/2020  Fund X   0.02740    3400000     20768759.59
31/05/2020  Fund X   0.02180    2000000     23265118.55
30/06/2020  Fund X   0.02270                23793236.74
31/07/2020  Fund X   0.01120                24059720.99
31/08/2020  Fund X   0.01260                24362873.47
30/09/2020  Fund X   0.00750                24545595.02
31/10/2020  Fund X   0.00410    -8110576    16502402.68
30/11/2020  Fund X   0.02790                16962819.72
31/12/2020  Fund X   0.01230                17171462.40
```

In the above, the Desired Output column is calculated by taking the previous row's Desired Output, plus any cashflow in the current period, times 1 + mtd_return. Effectively, I'm looking for a good way to calculate compounded returns in the face of external cashflows.

Many thanks!

Mike

Any help on implementing this in python would be appreciated.

Comment: Last time when I checked, Python was capable of multiplication and addition of numbers. It matters more how your input data looks like. Or do you get it in this actual format (text)?

Comment: Hi @tevemadar, no, it isn't text, its numeric. So those blanks are actually NaNs

Comment: @Mike use an example of one value to show how to get it. For example, how did you get the first value: 15552798.98.

Comment: @inquirer, thanks for the comment. The `first value  = 15687713 * (1+-0.0086)`.
Second value is then the (first value + cashflow) * (1+-0.009). So on and so forth.

Comment: Is it possible to upload Excel files to this forum? If so, it would be a lot easier to explain the formulae

Comment: @Mike answered you with my version in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('df7.txt', sep=',', header=0)

df['reportdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reportdate'])
df = df.fillna(0)

qqq = []

def func_data(x):
    a = 0
    ind = x.index[0] - 1
    if x.index[0] > 0:
        a = (qqq[ind] + x['cashflow']) * (1 + x['mtd_return'])
        qqq.append(a.values[0])
    else:
        qqq.append(df.loc[0, 'cashflow'] * (1 + df.loc[0, 'mtd_return']))


    return a


df.groupby(['reportdate']).apply(func_data)
df['new'] = qqq
print(df)
```

Output

```
   reportdate      fund  mtd_return    cashflow  Desired Output           new
0  2018-11-30    Fund X     -0.0086  15687713.0     15552798.98  1.555280e+07
1  2018-12-31    Fund X     -0.0090         0.0     15412823.78  1.541282e+07
2  2019-01-31    Fund X      0.0092         0.0     15554621.76  1.555462e+07
3  2019-02-28    Fund X      0.0063         0.0     15652615.88  1.565262e+07
4  2019-03-31    Fund X      0.0070         0.0     15762184.19  1.576218e+07
5  2019-04-30    Fund X      0.0122         0.0     15954482.84  1.595448e+07
6  2019-05-31    Fund X      0.0006   1000000.0     16964655.53  1.696466e+07
7  2019-06-30    Fund X      0.0057   1200000.0     18268194.07  1.826819e+07
8  2019-07-31    Fund X      0.0045         0.0     18350400.94  1.835040e+07
9  2019-08-31    Fund X      0.0021         0.0     18388936.78  1.838894e+07
10 2019-09-30    Fund X      0.0053         0.0     18486398.15  1.848640e+07
11 2019-10-31    Fund X      0.0020         0.0     18523370.94  1.852337e+07
12 2019-11-30    Fund X      0.0043         0.0     18603021.44  1.860302e+07
13 2019-12-31    Fund X      0.0066         0.0     18725801.38  1.872580e+07
14 2020-01-31    Fund X      0.0107         0.0     18926167.45  1.892617e+07
15 2020-02-29    Fund X     -0.0051         0.0     18829644.00  1.882964e+07
16 2020-03-31    Fund X     -0.1070         0.0     16814872.09  1.681487e+07
17 2020-04-30    Fund X      0.0274   3400000.0     20768759.59  2.076876e+07
18 2020-05-31    Fund X      0.0218   2000000.0     23265118.55  2.326512e+07
19 2020-06-30    Fund X      0.0227         0.0     23793236.74  2.379324e+07
20 2020-07-31    Fund X      0.0112         0.0     24059720.99  2.405972e+07
21 2020-08-31    Fund X      0.0126         0.0     24362873.47  2.436287e+07
22 2020-09-30    Fund X      0.0075         0.0     24545595.02  2.454559e+07
23 2020-10-31    Fund X      0.0041  -8110576.0     16502402.68  1.650240e+07
24 2020-11-30    Fund X      0.0279         0.0     16962819.72  1.696282e+07
25 2020-12-31    Fund X      0.0123         0.0     17171462.40  1.717146e+07
```

Made in your file all the values ​​separated by commas, empty too (that is, between commas is empty). Read a file in pandas and created a dataframe. header=0 means that the first row is used as column headers. Next, the 'reportdate ' column is converted to datetime format and empty values are replaced with zero. The data is grouped by date. The func_data function is created for the call. If this is the first call, then the code in else is calculated, the rest is in if. The calculations are written to the qqq array, which then populates the 'new' column.

Comment: Works a treat, thank you!